# How to add navigationController to tabBar Controller programmatically?

Tags: iphone

In AppDelegate.m I am writing following code for navigationbar.

```
MaterialsListViewController *materials = [[MaterialsListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MaterialsListView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:materials];
```

In the same AppDelegate.m I am writing following code for tabbar.

```
UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
viewController1 = [[[MaterialsListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MaterialsList" bundle:nil] autorelease];
viewController2 = [[[RecentMaterialsListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecentMaterialsList" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
NSArray *items = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items;
UITabBarItem *item1 = [items objectAtIndex:0];
[item1 setTitle:@"Materials"];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [items objectAtIndex:1];
[item2 setTitle:@"Recent"];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

How to add NavigationBar to the tabbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `UINavigationController`.

After you cretae `viewController1`

init a `UINavigationController` with a your viewController has RootViewController:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController_01 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)];
```

Then add the `navigationController_01` to `tabBarController.viewControllers`:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController_01, navigationController_02, nil];
```

Comment: @Fred: Hey Fred look the code properly. i am not missing UINAvigationCOntroller.  And i tried with self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController_01, navigationController_02, nil];

Comment: Yes, but when You add the viewControllers to tabBarController, If you want one, You should add a UINavigationController..
You are missing it in: `self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];`
Your are adding a `MaterialsListViewController` and a `RecentMaterialsListViewController`, which maybe are UIViewControllers

Comment: You should create first a the `MaterialsListViewController` then init a `UINavigationController` with `MaterialsListViewController` has root, and add the `UINavigationController` to your `tabBarController` viewControllers array, not the `MaterialsListViewController`..
get it??

Answer (score 1):

In the below line, you can pass `navigationcontroller` as a member of the array.

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: navigation, viewController2, nil];
```